# How create diferents log File with different content using log4 in java configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j, spring-batch

i am using **spring batch** and i need to create **different** log files one log for job, due to i acces to external properties file, i need to create configuration logs in **java code**. My canfiguration is

```
ConsoleAppender console = new ConsoleAppender();
    console.setLayout(new PatternLayout(stdoutConversionPattern));
    console.setThreshold(Level.INFO);
    console.activateOptions();
    Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(console);

    // FICHERO: FileAppender1.LOG CONTENDRA LA INFROMACION DE LA EJECUCION DEL FileAppender1
        RollingFileAppender FileAppender1Appender = new RollingFileAppender();
        FileAppender1Appender.setName("FileAppender1Logger");
        FileAppender1Appender.setFile(FileAppender1File);
        FileAppender1Appender.setLayout(new PatternLayout(FileAppender1ConversionPattern));
        FileAppender1Appender.setAppend(true);
        FileAppender1Appender.setMaxBackupIndex(FileAppender1MaxBackup);
        FileAppender1Appender.setMaxFileSize(FileAppender1MaxFileSize);
        FileAppender1Appender.activateOptions();
        Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(FileAppender1Appender);

    // FICHERO: FileAppender2.LOG CONTENDRA LA INFROMACION DE LA EJECUCION DEL FileAppender2
        RollingFileAppender FileAppender2Appender = new RollingFileAppender();
        FileAppender2Appender.setName("FileAppender2Logger");
        FileAppender2Appender.setFile(FileAppender2File);
        FileAppender2Appender.setLayout(new PatternLayout(FileAppender2ConversionPattern));
        FileAppender2Appender.setAppend(true);
        FileAppender2Appender.setMaxBackupIndex(FileAppender2MaxBackup);
        FileAppender2Appender.setMaxFileSize(FileAppender2MaxFileSize);
        FileAppender2Appender.activateOptions();
        Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(FileAppender2Appender);

        Logger.getRootLogger().setAdditivity(false);
        properties.put("logging.file", FileAppender2File);
```

And i write :

```
static final Logger FileAppender1Log = LogManager.getLogger("FileAppender1Logger");
static final Logger FileAppender1Log = LogManager.getLogger("FileAppender2Logger");
```

But **Always** the logger write en **all logs files** when i want have differents logger one log for job
Sorry for my english, not is my native languaje and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding both appender to Root configuration, thats why it is not able to differentiate different logger. You should add appender to Logger which you are interested like below

```
Logger.getLogger("FileAppender1Logger").addAppender(FileAppender1Appender);
Logger.getLogger("FileAppender2Logger").addAppender(FileAppender2Appender);
```